# Replacing SharePoint menu with custom asp.net menu

Tags: asp.net, dll, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom menu I built that I would like to deploy to my SharePoint Site's Master Page.

I have the asp.net menu build as a c# project is VS2010, but have no idea how to deploy it to SharePoint.  Once compiled, the project of course creates a dll file and has a few .config files.

Where can I place these files?  I heard in the GAC but I am not sure where that specifically is (folder) on the server.  Also, will I be required to Reference that dll in my project (point it to the GAC on the Sp2010 server)?

What is the standard, most accepted way of deploying a custom asp.net menu to a SharePoint Master Page?

Thanks

In Addition:
After playing with this, I create a VERY simple asp.net menu in Visual Studio 2010.  The following is the entirety of my default.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<html4f><body><head runat="server"></head>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
 <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu1" Value="Menu1">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="SubMenu1" Value="SubMenu1"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="SubMenu2" Value="SubMenu2"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu2" Value="Menu2"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
</form>
```

Root web folder after publish:

[image: Root]

Bin folder:

[image: Bin]

How do I add this to my SharePoint master page file?  I now realize I need to add the dll's (all of them?) to the Sharepoint BIN folder for that particular site collection, as well as modify the web.config file, but I am unsure how to find out the information I need to do so.  The .config files require some "keys" and I am unsure how to find out the GUID for the dll's I am using?
This should be a simple thing - add a menu to sharepoint, but finding I don't know what to search for in order to proceed.  Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

This is pretty simple actually -

1) The DLL and whatever config files you need should go to the Bin folder of the site (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\ViritualDirectories\\BIN).

2) Add the DLL to the GAC (This may or may not be required; if the control doesn't hit SharePoint, no security needed so GAC may not be required.

3) Add the control to the master page using @Register to include it in the page.

4) Add a "SafeControl" entry to the web.config file (required for SP to run the DLL) - you can see any one of the existing ones to see the format ***

*** If you are in a farm environment, updating the Web.config is not advisable by hand; in a farm (2+ servers), SharePoint likes to overwrite them.

Best Regards,

David M. Sterling

Author MOSS 2007 The Complete Reference

davidmsterling.blogspot.com

www.sterling-consulting.com

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I have some questions still that I hope you would be able to help me with:

1) I have the following files in my current BIN folder of my asp.net menu project:

App_Web_3qywcdph.dll
App_Web_5udcr0c.dll
App_global.asax.compiled
App-global.asax.dll
...do I add ALL these files?

2) I don't utilize any SharePoint in my menu - they are all static links.  I won't need this to be added to the GAC then?

Comment: 3) I am unsure about the @Register's "tagprefix" and "TagName".  What do I use here?  Also, the other @Register entries reference a asax file.  All my files are either dll's or aspx (?)

4) SafeControl entries require Assembly name, PublicKeyToken, NameSpace, Typename, etc.  Where do I find these? 

Thanks again